# How to share a list from one component to another one?

Tags: reactjs

App.jsx module:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Conduct from './extras/conduct';
import Vote from './extras/vote';
import Menu from './menu';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Menu/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Conduct}/>
          <Route path="/vote" component={Vote}/>
        </Switch>      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Conduct.jsx module:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Conduct.css';
import Election from './election';
class Conduct extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            owner:'',
            elename:'',
            newCandidate:'',
            Candidateslen:'0',
            addaddress:'',
            candName:[]
        }
    }
}
```

Vote.jsx module

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Vote extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <h2>you can vote here</h2>
        );
    }
}

export default Vote;
```

I come up with serious issue in my react.js code please help me. The state.candName is a state list in Conduct.jsx module and now i want to use this list elements in Vote.jsx module. How to do that.

Comment: The better way is to use redux in your project for store and use your states, changing candName in Conduct.jsx you can get an update in Vote.jsx

Comment: how redux will help me?

Comment: you can check the following answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65785994/how-to-share-data-from-one-react-native-component-to-another-component/65786436#65786436

Answer (score 1):

Use Redux as central store, where every component can access that data for you.

*How redux helps you?*  Redux will help your to store your  **Conduct.jsx** data in central store where data will be available to the all of your components with help of **connect** method from **react-redux**. You should study it how to use redux with React, It will help you a lot in this issues and for sure in future also.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state management library like `redux` to manage the central data store for all app data which can be accessed by any component. For more, please have a look into the official documentation https://react-redux.js.org/

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much