# Is there a way that I can use a custom hook in a class-based component?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

I have this hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { auth } from "../firebase/auth-service"

const useFirebaseAuthentication = () => {
   const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState(null);

   useEffect(() => {
       const unlisten = auth.onAuthStateChanged(
           authUser => {
               authUser
                   ? setAuthUser(authUser)
                   : setAuthUser(null);
           },
       );
       return () => {
           unlisten();
       }
   });

   return authUser
}

export default useFirebaseAuthentication;
```

That I use like this:

const authUser = useFirebaseAuthentication();

Is there a way I could use this hook useFirebaseAuthentication() in a class-based component?

Comment: if you want know how to share between components, look the following answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65785994/how-to-share-data-from-one-react-native-component-to-another-component/65786436#65786436

Comment: class have states which are equivalent of hooks. you can share a hook value to class based component, but they should have a paent child relationship

Answer (score 2):

Class based components directly donot support Hooks.

Read [React-FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both)

You can create a `Higher Order Component`, like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useFirebaseAuthentication} from '../hooks/useFirebaseAuthentication';

export const withFireBaseAuthHookHOC = (Component: any) => {
  return (props: any) => {
    const authUser = useFirebaseAuthentication();

    return <Component authUser ={authUser} {...props} />;
  };
};
```

Now just wrap your class based component with this `HOC`.

.